# Function property is not a function in Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, polymer

I am using the Polymer framework for my project in which I'm declaring a function callback in properties and trying to call it from another function. But on accessing it I'm getting an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: this.callback is not a function

Please have a look into this.

```
Polymer({
  is: "parent-dom",
  properties: {
    people: {
      type: String,
      value: "df"
    },
    item: {
      type: String,
      value: "asdf",
      notify: true
    },
    callback: {
      type: Object,
      value: function(index) {
        console.log("Inside  callback function");
      }
    },

  },
  showTargetColorDialog: function(e) {
    this.callback("sadf");
  }
});
```

Comment: Try `this.properties.callback`.

Comment: @31piy nope not working

Comment: What calls `showTargetColorDialog`?

Comment: i have a button whose action is linked to showTargetColorDialog.

Comment: How is it so linked?

Comment: @Ry-  <button on-tap="showTargetColorDialog">Send front to back</button>

Comment: Polymer might be trying to do a serialization thing with the `callback` property. Does changing it to `type: Function` (which opts out of serialization according to [this comment](https://github.com/Polymer/docs/issues/1962#issuecomment-295017785), at least) help?

Comment: In your definition `callback` is a property and it's initial value is set by running that function. And since it doesn't return anything the value would be undefined. So you're trying to use a property (so something that is not a function) as a function call. To define a method you would have it on the same "level" as `showTargetColorDialog`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please provide more details about what you would like to achieve, since specify *Polymer properties as functions* it's not very common case?

So you could declare public methods on your element, like you did with `showTargetColorDialog`, and they will be accessible to be called like:

`document.querySelector('parent-dom').showTargetColorDialog();`

But again it's not very "Polymer way" to that.

To answer your **original question**, if you really need set callback *as Polymer property* (I'm still not sure why), but you could:

```
callback: {
  type: Object,
  value: function() {
    return function(index) {
        console.log("Inside callback function ", index);
    };
  }
},
```

And then you will be able to call `this.callback('something');`